# How does pickle preserve methods on a python object?

Tags: pickle

I've saved a numpy array using pickle. When I load it back, without importing numpy, I get:

```
import pickle

fname = "temp"

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)

a.sum()
> 2.16....
```

How is this possible? My question can be interpreted as "how does pickle work"?